# Best practice for keeping Fragments for later display

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library

I have an activity with a `FrameLayout` in it.
The activity should show four steps, and each step is a `Fragment`. When I want to go back-further, I don't want my fragments to be recreated. I would like to retain them and simply replace their view in my fragment.

I used to first create my Fragments and add them in the backstack like this:

```
Fragment step= new Frag1ActCompleteFragsCommTrack();
FragmentTransaction ft= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(step, ""+onStepNr);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

notice that I don't show it, I simply create it and add to the backstack.

So, once I need one of my fragments to show, I add it (in this example I don't remove any fragment from the `framelayout` just because it's my first add):

```
FragmentTransaction ft= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.my_frameLayout, step);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.commit();
```

So: the problem is that I obtain a

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: Frag1ActCompleteFragsCommTrack{410dcb20 #0 id=0x7f050041 -1}

But I think I can't add directly into my framelayout the first time, otherwise the next time I replace it, I could lose my fragment. Am I right? So.. what's the best practice for retaining fragments that could interchange each other in a framelayout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ladies and gentlemen, I did it!

If you add a `Fragment`, and you want it to be shown in a `framelayout`, remember to put it in the Fragment backstack. That's it! If you replace it in the framelayout with another one, no worries: you can put it back by finding it thanks to its tag.
It was easier than I thought actually

```
//step is an int describing the step associated to the fragment I wanna place
FragmentTransaction ft= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.act_complete_track_frameLayout, f, ""+step);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
if(firstAttach)
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

imagine a fragment with tag "1" replaced through the code above by a fragment with tag "2". If I want to go back to step1, I reuse that code by obtaining my old fragment with `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("1")`

To be short, I thought that `FragmentTransaction.replace` removed the `fragment` from the backstack as well. That seems not to be the case (luckily)

Comment: If anyone could confirm my impression about `FragmentTransaction.replace` would be nice. The documentation is a bit vague about this issue.

Comment: I would have expected findFragmentByTag() to return null on a replaced fragment.

Comment: me too, but it does not seem to behave like that. Is it maybe because of the v4 support library implementation?

Comment: wouldn't think... what happens when you navigate back to a removed fragment using the back button?  is it actually still there? [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664670/delete-one-specific-fragment-from-the-android-backstack) suggest maybe its a ghost fragment?

Comment: back button pops the fragments previously added. `Replace` isn't really doing what we expect. You were right: the right way of doing this is using `show` and `hide`

Answer (score 1):

You can always do something like [fragmentManager.putFragment(yourFragment);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#putFragment%28android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment%29)

Comment: Humm, good point! I'll think about that! I was thinking about this solution, but I'm not sure if it'll work:
`ft.remove(fragmentToRetain);
ft.add(fragmentToRetain, fragmentToRetain.getTag());
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.add(R.id.act_complete_track_frameLayout, step); //new step here!           ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);`
ft.commit()`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to add all the fragments but not show them until you are ready.  `FragmentTransaction.add()` doesn't exactly do that though.  It will also be shown after its added.  You should use `hide()` after adding each fragment, and then later you can use `show()` to make it visible, and `hide()` again to make other fragments invisible.

Like this:

```
Fragment step = new Frag1ActCompleteFragsCommTrack();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(step, ""+onStepNr);
ft.hide(step);
ft.commit();
```

Then later:

```
Fragment step = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(""+onStepNr);
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.show(step);
// may want to hide other fragments here
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Nope! I'm trying to do something like a "step to step" form. Each fragment contains a step. But I want to add the chance of going back (i.e. from the fourth back to the second step and vice versa).
The fragments are created the first time is needed. For example: if I go from the first to the second step, I create the second step fragment. But good piece of suggestion anyway! I could have use that way as well!