# can the order of the fragments in the backstack be changed programmatically

Tags: android, fragment-backstack

Having A->B->c in back stack, A is at top.
At the time it would like to have C to be on top, and keep A, B in the order in the stack. In the requirement it cannot have two C instances in the stack. The problem is if pop the C then all A, B is removed.

What it wants is to have C->A->B now.

Is it possible to achieve this with FragmentManager's api?

Comment: There is a reason it is called a stack, I don't think there is an API, but depending on your use case, there is always an approach to get it to work !!

Comment: I think it is already answered in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665346/android-reorder-fragment-backstack

Comment: Maybe creating a new stack with the desired order, or maybe using reflection to modify the actual one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FragmentManager`does not readily support changing the ordering of the backstack or removing items that aren't at the top of the stack.

You may want to consider managing your own version of a Fragment backstack.

Comment: yeap, wish to have built in support from Android.

Answer (score 1):

**put below code inside your activiy**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager  


//add fragment A 
fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager .beginTransaction();
ft.add(resId, fragmentA);
ft.addToBackstack("tag");
ft.commit();

//add fragmentB
fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager .beginTransaction();
ft.replace(resId, fragmentB);
ft.addToBackstack("tag1");
ft.commit();

//add fragmentC
fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager .beginTransaction();
ft.replace(resId, fragmentC);
ft.addToBackstack("tag2");
ft.commit();

 //then try to take back click of B and C fragment here through interface

//backclick of C
public void backClick()
{
fragmentManager.popBackStack("tag1",0);
}

//back click of B
public void backClick1()
{
fragmentManager.popBackStack("tag",0);
}
```

Comment: the pop BackStackwill destroy the fragment. Thanks for share!

Answer (score 0):

keep fragment hide and if you want show it.