# Remove specific fragment from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have 2 fragments(Frag A, Frag B) which are shown in multi pane in landscape with different container id (R.id.containerA,R.id.containerB) respectively.

My screen flow for 1st fragment is FragA->FragA1->FragA2

My screen flow for 2nd fragment is FragB->FragB1

I am adding each fragment to backstack. So I have around 5 fragments in backstack.

Actual order of navigating is FragA->FragB->FragA1->FragB1->FragA2

Now when I press back button, I want FragB1 to be popped out first from backstack instead of FragA2. I know fragments are maintained in a stack but how to handle this particular multi pane scenario ?

Should I use reflection like mentioned in this post ?
[Android Reorder Fragment Backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665346/android-reorder-fragment-backstack/22125826#22125826)

Any other alternatives ?

Answer (score -1):

If you simply want to get FragB1 instead of FragA2, you can check by obtaining the name of the fragment and then go one step back if name of the fragment is FragA2. You can get the name using the following code:

```
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry=getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getActivity().getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()-1);
String str=backEntry.getName();
```

Comment: After getting the name, is it possible to pop only Frag B1 out? I think A2 also will be popped since backstack is a LIFO.

Comment: By definition, yes A2 would also have been popped by the time you pop B1 out. But what you can do is put A2 back into the stack if you hold a reference to it.