# Fragment navigation in menu

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a common layout where I have a menu in a `DrawerLayout` and these menu items replace the visible main fragment in my `Activity`. The top menu item represents my Home screen(fragment A). When I press something else(fragment B) in the menu I replace A with B and add the transaction to the back stack (A -> B). If I select fragment C from the menu I would like the back stack now to be A -> C. In order to do that I call `popBackStack()` and then replace A with C.

My issue here is that I would like the transition between B and C to be smooth but when I call `popBackStack()`, fragment A is visible for a split second before it's replaced with C. So what I want is basically creating a `FragmentTransaction` where I can pop the back stack without committing it before I replace A with C.

To clarify: I should note that when you are in fragment B you could select something there that would take you deeper so the stack would then be A -> B -> B1. If I press C from the menu at this point I need to clear the backstack and show C WITHOUT flashing A in the process.

Does anyone know if that is possible or does anybody have any other solution to my issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete one specific fragment from the Android backstack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664670/delete-one-specific-fragment-from-the-android-backstack)

Comment: can you explain why you want to popBackStack() and then replace a fragment ??

Comment: Because I don't want fragment B to stay in the back stack when I go into fragment C. Pressing back from C should result in A.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add any of fragment in back stack. Just replace one with another. In this way we will skip to call popBackStack().

Comment: That would work if I didn't need a back stack. I edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've solved this issue, but I have been working on a library that should help you solve your navigation issues!

Since the implementation of the ChildFragmentManager it has given us flexibility in creating back stacks within individual fragments. I am leveraging this in the library. It's accessible in jcenter repository, please see the ReadMe for implementation details!

https://github.com/DMCApps/NavigationFragment

Basically you will need to use a `SingleStackNavigationManagerFragment` as your base fragment. When the menu item from A->B is clicked, call `present(B)` on the navigation manager (or the within FragmentA). When you want to add C to the stack but remove B, you can call `clearNavigationStackToRoot`. This will clear the current navigation stack to the first fragment that you added to the manager (aka FragmentA) without any navigation. Then `present(C)`. This will cause no animation to occur for the `clearNavigationStackToRoot`, but will show an animation for the `present(C)`.

If you need more clarification I can add a sample to my repository for you. The more samples the more resources people will have to utilize my library!

I have added an example of what you need under the DrawerClearStackExample package in the sample application for the library.

Thanks,
DMCApps